# Git push failed to GCP source repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, git

For a few days, `git push` is failing:

```
$ git push -v
Pushing to https://source.developers.google.com/p/xxxxxxx
Counting objects: 6546, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3171/3171), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (6546/6546), 4.28 GiB | 44.99 MiB/s, done.
Total 6546 (delta 2676), reused 5369 (delta 1598)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It's systematic. The repository is heavy (19Gi), and contains lot of files.
Was working fine during years.
It's not a permission issue (`pull` is working).
Does anyone have an idea why it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your git config to not chunk large files.

A trivial fix is to tell git to not chunk until some ridiculously large size value, such as

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Check similar issue and other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790232/hanging-at-post-git-receive-pack-chunked)

Comment: Did not fix the issue, even with a larger value: `git config http.postBuffer 1524288000`. Thx anyway :)

Comment: One of the other answer was to try pushing with SSH. Also 19Gi looks a bit much. What if there is a let's say a 20Gi limit. Can you try and push the same thing to other GCP but smaller repos?